# Find $1/x+1/y+1/z$

Tags: exponential-function

The values are as follows:
$p^{x-1}=qr,r^{z-1}=pq,q^{y-1}=rp$

I have to find:
$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}$$

What I have tried so far:
$$\frac{p^x}{p}=qr,\frac{q^y}{q}=rp,\frac{r^z}{r}=pq$$
$$p^x=pqr,q^y=pqr,r^z=pqr$$

I am not sure if this part is correct. However, it does point to an option - $1$
$$p^x=p^1q^1r^1$$
$$x=1$$
$$\text{Similarly},y=1,z=1$$

$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1}=1$$

I don't think this part is correct. How can I simplify this further?

Also, there are 4 options given:
$$2$$
$$1$$
$$3$$
$$0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly showed, we have :
$$p^x = q^y = r^z = pqr$$
This implies that :
\begin{align}
p &= (pqr)^{1/x} \\
q &= (pqr)^{1/y} \\
r &= (pqr)^{1/z}
\end{align}
Multiplying the $3$ equations, we get :
$$pqr = (pqr)^{1/x+1/y+1/z}$$
I am guessing a hypothesis is that $p,q,r$ are positive real number. If this is the case, we must have : $$\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z = 1$$

(Note that this means your result $x=y=z=1$ is *false*)

Answer (score 0):

I assume $p,q,r \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$

We've
$$x=\log_{p}qr +1 =\log_{p}(pqr)$$
$$y=\log_{q}rp +1=\log_{q}(pqr)$$
$$z=\log_{r}pq +1=\log_{r}(pqr) $$

Therefore
$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{\ln p +\ln q +\ln r}{\ln pqr}=1$$

Answer (score -1):

$$p^x=pqr, p=pqr^\frac{1}{x}$$
$$r^z=pqr, r=pqr^\frac{1}{z}$$
$$q^y=pqr, q=pqr^\frac{1}{y}$$

$$pqr= pqr^{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{y}}$$

$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{y}=1$$